# A single multi-dimensional array key suddenly disappears?

Tags: php, serialization, multidimensional-array, deserialization

I am using a Multi-Dimension array to store some information within a script. There are hundreds of additional keys, but this is what the first three look like (private information censored):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => LAST NAME
            [first_name] => COLLEEN
            [middle_name] => F
            [dob] => 00/00/87
            [sex] => F
            [race] => W
            [city] => SOME CITY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => LAST NAME
            [first_name] => COLLEEN
            [middle_name] => F
            [dob] => 00/00/87
            [sex] => F
            [race] => W
            [city] => SOME CITY
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => LAST NAME
            [first_name] => STEPHANIE
            [middle_name] => L
            [dob] => 00/00/74
            [sex] => F
            [race] => W
            [city] => SOME CITY
        )
)
```

I want to eliminate duplicate key values, such as `$array[1]`, which is a duplicate of `$array[0]`. To do that, I do this:

```
function multi_array_unique($array)
{
  $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));

  foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
      $result[$key] = multi_array_unique($value);
    }
  }

  return $result;
}

$unique_array = multi_array_unique($array);
$unique_array = array_values($unique_array);
```

Now, this does a FANTASTIC job of removing all the duplicates in the array... Except one little thing that I haven't been able to figure out. This is how the array now looks:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => LAST NAME
            [first_name] => COLLEEN
            [middle_name] => F
            [dob] => 00/00/87
            [race] => W
            [city] => SOME CITY
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => LAST NAME
            [first_name] => STEPHANIE
            [middle_name] => L
            [dob] => 00/00/74
            [sex] => F
            [race] => W
            [city] => SOME CITY
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [last_name] => LAST NAME
            [first_name] => ASIA
            [middle_name] => ALIA
            [dob] => 00/00/88
            [sex] => F
            [race] => B
            [city] => SOME CITY
        )
)
```

Where the heck did `$array[0]["sex"]` go??? This is the only one missing, I checked over every other of the 93 keys in this dataset. Only `$array[0]` is missing the `["sex"]` key. I'm totally stumped here. You guys have any ideas?

**Edit:**

Ray was able to provide a working solution to achieve my desired results, but **I still would like to know what causes the original error.**

Here is Ray's working code (adapted into a function):

```
function multi_array_unique($multi_array)
{
    $newArray = array();
    foreach($multi_array as $subArray) {
        if(!in_array($subArray, $newArray)) {
            $newArray[] = $subArray;
        }
    }

  return $newArray;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid only 100% duplicate sub arrays in the main array?  If a similar array had even one value different, would you want to keep it?

Comment: Maybe PHP doesn't want to have sex XD

Comment: Are array[0] and array[1] also the only duplicates in the 93 keys?

Comment: i know this doesn't help. but we could state the problem as: when colleen lost her duplicate, she stopped having sex. that made me laugh. could't resist pointing it out

Comment: @Ray That is correct. I only want to disregard 100% duplicates.

Comment: @Asad No, I start off with approx. 242 keys and end up with 96 (0-95).

Comment: use [var_export](http://www.php.net/var_export)() to give us an array we can copy/paste and try for ourselves.

Comment: Perhaps use [codepad.org](http://codepad.org)

Comment: @jdstankosky Do you really need that `foreach` loop withih `multi_array_unique()`?

Comment: @rambocoder `private information censored`

Comment: More seriously, try to see what is the result of array_map("serialize", $array) and array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array))

Comment: @Asad, is that another pun on the whole missing key thing? lol

Comment: @ArthurJaouen What you asked to see is found here: http://pastebin.com/abNEgQx5

Comment: @jdstankosky Nothing abnormal here, I really don't have a clue.

Answer (score 1):

try this to get rid of duplicate members:

```
$newArray = new array();
 foreach($originalArray as $subArray){
     if(!in_array($subArray, $newArray){
         $newArray[] = $subArray;
      }
  }
```

The array $newArray should only have unique members of the original array.

Comment: Fixed some typo's, but this method works great. Thank you. I'd still like to know what's going on with the original method.